# Register your app as Photo Editor

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I want my app to be available as photo editor and it should appear as an option when the user chooses to edit the photo. I can see Nokia Creative Studio, OneShot and other apps there, but My app doesn't appear. How do I register for this?

I am not aware of the terminology which is used for this, so couldn't search about it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh.. finally found it. The term is `Rich Media Extensibility` (Dunno who gives these complex names to easy features).

[The MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) describes it properly with examples.